# Matlab text() in figure - FontSize property not working

Tags: matlab

I want to show some text in a plot and adjust the fontsize. In the [matlab reference](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html) I found it should be something like this:

```
text(.025,0.6,descr,'FontSize',20);
```

However, if I do this the fontsize is still the default 10px. I do not get any errors. The following does work:

```
text(.025,0.6,descr,'Color','red');
```

And this gives me an error, for unkown property:

```
text(.025,0.6,descr,'Size',20);
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? I work on Matlab R2014a on Linux Mint.

Comment: It does work for me in Matlab R2014a on Win7. What do you get for `get(text,'FontUnit')`? What is your text `descr`, anything special?

Comment: Thanks for your response! `get(text,'FontUnit')` returns `points`. The `descr` is a 9x1 cell array, each cell containing a string.